# jQuery check if input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get it where, if there is value in the input, go ahead and do your thing but if there isn't, don't do anything. I keep getting getting it where, if there is nothing in the input, a failure message occurs but only if I hit the enter key
jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/8ovrmhgp click the space in the lower right corner, then press enter. It shouldn't pop up, because the input is not focused.
login/failure jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    var login = [marion, 'FATHER1'];

    var marion = $('#logging').val();
    marion = marion.toUpperCase();

    if (marion !== 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
      alert('Login Failed');
  } else if (marion === 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
    $('.notify').css('margin-top', '0');
      $('#logging').val('');
  }

  });
  $('.exit').on('click', function(){
    $('.notify').slideUp('slow');
  });
});
```

Comment: looks like you answered your own question with your code, what's the issue?

Comment: what do you mean not working? you want the `enter key` detection to be global or once the input is focused?

Comment: once it's focused. If the input is not focused, and you click enter, don't do anything. If the input is focused, and you click enter, do something.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BBaughn/8ovrmhgp/ click the space in the lower right corner, then press enter. It shouldn't pop up, because the input is not focused

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to check if an input is empty, I'm guessing `#logging` is the input:

```
$('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    var marion = $('#logging').val();
    if (marion == '') {
       //this means the input value was empty
    }
});
```

Comment: @DominatorX sorry, no need for `indexOf`, just match it against an empty string should be enough. Don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get what you mean now. You're checking the entire document for keypresses as is, you need to check the input only. I think this is a good solution to do that:

```
$('.login input').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !$('#logging').val()) {
        e.PreventDefault();
    } else if (e.which == 13 && $('.btn1').focus()) {
        $('.btn1').click();
    }
});
```

[Working Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9m4p9u59/)

Comment: I know how to check the value, and the website isn't going to be public, which is why I'm coding it front end. The website is for my family, to update their profile, etc.

Comment: If you know, I'm not sure why you're asking. :)

Comment: because I'm talking about where you hit the enter key. When I hit the enter key without the input even being focused, it'll throw the "Login Failed" error

Comment: For some reason that didn't work in my actual code. What I just did was edit my if statement saying "if this is not 'FATEHR1', then send this alert." I figured that out when I changed the e.preventDefault(); to an alert and didn't get it. so, here is my new if statement: if (marion !== 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
          alert('Login Failed');
      } else if (marion === 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
        $('.notify').css('margin-top', '0');
          $('#logging').val('');
      }

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Works for me even with your new code. If you add an alert instead of `preventDefault` it does pop up. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

if the length is equal zero, that means the field is empty. It works after adding length === 0 check, please try this,

```
if (e.which == 13 && $('.btn1').val().length === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else if (e.which == 13 && $('.btn1').focus()) {
    $('.btn1').click();
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about, if the value is empty and you hit the enter key. I'll have to edit my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn1').on('click', function(){
    var login = [marion, 'FATHER1'];

    var marion = $('#logging').val();
    marion = marion.toUpperCase();

    if (marion !== 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
      alert('Login Failed');
  } else if (marion === 'FATHER1' && $('#logging').val()) {
    $('.notify').css('margin-top', '0');
      $('#logging').val('');
  }

  });
  $('.exit').on('click', function(){
    $('.notify').slideUp('slow');
  });
});
```

I didn't realize that my if statement was if the input wasn't detecting the right login, so it didn't matter if it was out of focus. Now it says "if it's not FATHER1 and there is value in the input only, then send this alert"